# Problems with my a link hover bold

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my a: link hover bold in that for some reason one of my links appears OK initially and then when I scroll to the bottom of the page the link text appears thinner than all the others.

It's only happening on link from a total of 7, all of which use the li tags.

Does anybody know why?

My code looks something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="">
    <div id="">
        <a href="file:">
            <img src=file>
    </div>
    <div id="">
        <li>Link</li>
    </div>
</div></a>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
li { 

display: inline;    
padding: 15px;
border: 5px solid grey;
background-color: white; 
border-radius: 5px 5px;
font-size: 25px;
color: silver;}

a {

text-decoration: none;
color: silver;
font-weight: none;
font-size: 25px;}

a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
color: silver;}
```

Comment: you need to close CSS selectors... `a{  ...  }`

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid: the `<a>` tag isn't closed, img's src value isn't enclosed in quotes and there's a `<li>` without `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: sorry, should have said, they are closed in the css file, I was having  trouble quoting them here for some reason

Comment: One other thing as well - there is no such value `font-weight: none;`. What you need is `font-weight: normal;` instead.

Comment: Please show the actual code. You're going to get irrelevant answers and comments otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

your `<a>` tag should have a closing part. I do not see any closing `</a>` in your presented code. Add `</a>` any where appropriate.

Comment: have closed tags, only seem to experience the issue in Safari